# Получение прямой ссылки на видеопоток со страницы сайта

Tags: c#, html, видео, link

Собираюсь писать софт для отслеживания и автоматической записи трансляций с сайта myfreecams.com. Просто так в исходном коде страницы нет прямой ссылки на видеопоток, которую можно было бы сразу передать на ffmpeg. Но, если зайти на сайт через мобильную версию m.myfreecams.com, представиться как ipad и не иметь flash-плагина, то видео трансляции будет отображаться через html5. В тех же chrome и firefox в контекстном меню видео есть возможность скопировать прямую ссылку на поток. Как достать эту ссылку средствами C# ?

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то напишет конечное решение. А так по идее изучить как прямую ссылку получает хтмл5 плейер, посмотреть в снифере запросы и ответы, почитать js на странице и сделать точно такой же алгоритм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел [mfc-node](https://github.com/sstativa/mfc-node) - реализацию мною задуманного на JS. Воспроизвести тоже самое на C# будет уже не сложно.